# C++ Qt framework: qmake exits with error code 2, can not find project.pro file, yet it's there

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

As the title says, I am having an issue with Qt Creator. I started to play with it and created a main() with a some code in it and when I wanted to compile it to see how it would appear on the screen, I am unable to do so, I see the following error:

> Cannot find file:
>   /Users/Eugene/Documents/Qt/Test/test.pro. Le processus
>   "/Users/Eugene/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/473/gcc/bin/qmake" terminated with
>   error cade 2. Error during the compilation of the project Test (build : Desktop)
>   during the step 'qmake'

Yet when I go to the folder, I can see the test.pro file there, so I don't see why Qt is unhappy.

Did anybody have had a similar problem? I couldn't find any similar question so far.
Thanks in advance for you help,
Regards

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you sure that you don't have space or other 'weird' characters in your project's path? If so, Qt is unhappy.

You may also try to delete the `*.pro.user` file and try to compile again.
If unfortunately neither of them work, you can try to compile your project on the command line.

`cd` to the root directory of your project and:

1. `qmake -project`
2. `mingw32-make`

If this still can't get your project compiled, you should check your Qt installation.

Answer (score 3):

In my case removing non-ascii characters from the path solved the problem. Spaces are fine, at least from my experience.

Answer (score 1):

I found another solution that worked for me.

QT is cross-platform tool, so it needs some limitations and restrictions.
One of this restriction is correct path to project. It CAN'T contain any spaces!!!

For example

**D:\Qt project\project -- wrong**

is WRONG. (notice space between Qt and Project).
Instead use something like this

**D:\Qt_project\project  -- correct**

Comment: Strange strange. I have working Qt project in directory with spaces :) (running on OS X 10.9 with Qt 5.3)