# qmake cannot find file

Tags: macos, qt

System: Mac OSX Yosemite.

I installed qt 4.8.7 from homebrew, and then went to a directory I cloned from github (MagRead @ https://github.com/ieatlint/MagRead.git).

I ran:

```
qmake MagRead.pro
```

and got this error:

```
Cannot find file: magread.pro.
```

But the file is clearly in the directory!

I googled and found [one similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7235367/c-qt-framework-qmake-exits-with-error-code-2-can-not-find-project-pro-file) on here on Stack Overflow, but the answers didn't help me.

I'm a noob to qt so any help is appreciated on how to get this project to build. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File names are case sensitive. Try

```
qmake magread.pro
```

Or just this, if directory name is also `magread` or if there is just one .pro file in current directory:

```
qmake
```

Comment: Thanks, the second way worked after I renamed the directory `magread`!

Comment: After I ran `make` I now have this error:
`In file included from magread.cpp:20:
./magread.h:37:10: fatal error: 'QAudioInput' file not found
#include <QAudioInput>
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [magread.o] Error 1`

Comment: I checked my qt folder and it does have the qtmultimedia and QAudioInput files... :(

Comment: @beagle I looked at the git repo you linked to, and actually there seems to be both `MagRead.pro` and `magread.pro`, one is symbolic link to the other. This is a bit strange, and may have messed something up when you did *git clone* or something else. I'd get rid of the symbolic link, and verify that the remaining .pro file is correct one and looks ok. Anyway, it seems to have `QT+=multimedia` in it, so if you can't figure it out, you should perhaps ask a new question (include relevant snippet of *Compile Output* in the question, which shows the command and the error).

Comment: Interesting! I just noticed that too. I did as you recommended and it still doesn't work, so I'll go ahead and ask a new question then. Thanks for your help, hyde!